# Experiencing problem with S6 Memo, with memos self duplicating by the hundreds. How do I stop the duplications?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Experiencing problem with S6 Memo, with memos self duplicating by the hundreds.  How do I stop the duplications and is there an efficient to delete the duplicates ?

Comment: I personally don't recommend using Samsung's Memo app at all unless they have improved it since I tested it.  When I tested it, Samsung's Memo app had ***no export functionality***.